# Auto start outlook using vbacript prompts password always

Tags: vbscript, scheduled-tasks

I am running scheduled task with below VBScript but it always prompt password for Outlook. I tried to make it remember in Outlook but it does not affect in schedule task start and never asks for the password if I start Outlook manually. How can I fix this issue?

Code:

```
Set WShell = WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
WShell.run("outlook")
```

Here's how I run the scheduled task:

[image: Scheduled task first screen.]

[image: Scheduled task 3rd screen]

[image: Scheduled task 4th screen]

[image: Scheduled task 5th screen]

[[image: first screen]

Comment: The issue is in your task scheduler settings not VBS. So post  them.

Comment: Attached screenshots of scheduled task settings.

Comment: You did not post the first page but page 2 twice.

Comment: No its not attached.

Comment: Please find it now.

Comment: Awaiting for your response.

Comment: Any solutions ..

Comment: Noodles,do you have solution or not?

Comment: does Admin-PC\admin have an outlook account?

Comment: Outlook account is configured in Admin-pc\admin user but email address is different to system user.

Comment: Any body has solution for this issue?